# Accessing Java nested classes from FreeMarker templates

Tags: java, freemarker

```
public class MyModel {

  private final com.google.gson.Gson gson = new Gson();
  private final SomeData someData = new SomeData();

  private class SomeData extends JsonModel() {
    String text = "text";
  }

  private class JsonModel() {
    public String toJson() {
      return gson.toJson(this);
    }
  }

  public SomeData getSomeData() {
    return someData;
  }
}
```

Assuming `MyModel` is accessible in FTL as `myModel`, why do `myModel.someData.toJson` or `myModel.getSomeData().toJson()` fail with `The following has evaluated to null or missing: myModel.someData.toJson` or `The following has evaluated to null or missing: myModel.getSomeData().toJson()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JsonModel` must be public, or else its members won't be exposed.

Comment: It was always going to be a silly error. I was thinking you can't have two top-level classes marked public in the same file, failing to notice this was actually an inner class. Thanks for pointing it out.